# link submit to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, form-submit

I have this form:

in header of my website:

```
<% form_tag request.path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search User", :name => nil %>
</p>
  <% end %>
```

controller:

```
  def index
    @title  = "All users"
    @users  = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @users1 = User.simple_search(params[:query]).all
    end
```

model:

```
acts_as_simply_searchable :columns => [:name, :email]
```

view

```
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users1 %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

displays a user

I want to link the submit button to index.html.erb (i have assigned a path in routes.rb). So that the user can look at the search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do this at the submit button, but at the form_tag URL (the first parameter). It would be something like this:

```
<% form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search User", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `request.path` to the desired path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the '=' sign and string interpolating the 'request.path' 
This Worked for me:

```
<%= form_tag "#{request.path}", method: "get" %>
  ...the rest of your code ...
<% end %>
```